# What is the meaning of the keyword "do", in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've seen a couple of `do` in Ruby, and I couldn't find a really good explanation of its purpose. For example, a place where I saw a `do` was in the `gemfile`:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'rspec-its'
    gem 'simplecov', :require => false
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'spork-rails'
    gem 'guard-spork'
    gem 'childprosess'
    gem 'rails-erd'
    gem 'pry-rails'
    gem 'guard-rails'
    gem 'guard-livereload'
    gem 'guard-bundler'
end
```

I know what this code does, but I don't know the purpose of `do`. I have my guesses, but I want them confirmed or denied by someone who knows more than me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`do ... end` (or alternatively `{ ... }`) creates a so-called block, which is a type of anonymous function in Ruby. In your example that block is passed as an argument to `group`. `group` then does some bookkeeping to set the given groups as active, executes the block, and then deactivates the groups again.

Answer (score 5):

The `do` keyword is used together with the `end` keyword to delimit a code block.

More info on the difference of `do end` with brackets may be found here: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000015

Comment: `do` is also used in `while`, `until`, and `for`/`in` loops to delimit the loop condition from the loop body, the same way the `then` keyword is used in `if`, `unless`, and `case` expressions.

Answer (score 5):

It is a `block` In other programming languages you using brackets, like this: `{}`. In `ruby` you can use:

```
do

  #something code

end
```